# What is fastest method for mean more than two arrays of floats?

Tags: java, list, mean

I have about 200 lists of the kind `(index , float)` and I want to calculate the mean between them, I know the way with the complexity time of `O(first Array size + ... + last Array size)` is there any solution to calculate the mean with the better complexity time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no possible way to calculate a mean of N independent items with time complexity less than `O(n)`: since you have to visit every item at least once to calculate the total.

If you want to beat O(n) complexity, then you will need to do something special, e.g.:

- Use pre-computed sums for sub-lists
- Exploit known dependencies in the data (e.g. certain elements being equal)

Of course, complexity does not always equate directly to speed. If you want to do it *fast* then there are plenty of other techniques (using concurrency or parallelism for example). But they will still be O(n) in complexity terms.

Answer (score 0):

You approach it by `divide and conquer`. For that you can use `ExecutorService`

Comment: is divide an conquer better than calculating all together?

Comment: Definitely.. Google for Merge sort you will get more

Comment: I know what the merge sort is, but if I want to merge three arrays, is it better to merge two and then merge the result with the third or it would be better to merge the three at once?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you read in your lists/arrays, you could add together the floats while reading them into memory. Dividing the value by the size of the arrays is cheap. Therefore you don't need to process the values twice.

If you use a `Collection` class for storing the values, you could extend e.g. `ArrayList` and override the `add()` method to update a `sum` field and provide a `getMean()` method.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no better way than including every element in the calculation (which is `O(first Array size + ... + last Array size)`), at least not for the problem as stated. If the lists were to have some special properties or you want to recalculate the mean repeatedly after adding, removing or changing elements or lists, it would be a different story.

An informal proof:

Assume you managed to calculate the mean by skipping one element. Logically you'd get to the same mean by changing the skipped element to any other value (since we skipped it, its value doesn't matter). But, in this case, the mean should be different. Thus you must use every element in the calculation.

Comment: you said: "If the lists were to have some special properties or you want to recalculate the mean repeatedly after adding, removing or changing elements or lists, it would be a different story." I changed my question and explained more, what is your idea now?